# I want to select from store after dispatching an action

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

I need to select from store and check if there is no data then dispatch an action then re-select from store again

this is my current code

```
      this.subscriptions.add(
        this.store
          .select(fromSharedStore.getIbmerEntityByQuery({ q }))
          .pipe(debounceTime(250))
          .subscribe(x => {
            if (x) {
              this.flatChildren = x.map(v => ({
                ...v,
                name: v.cn ? v.cn[0] : '',
                email: v.emailaddress ? v.emailaddress[0] : '',
                short_name: v.cn[0],
                parent: 'Author',
                search_id: v.cn[0],
              }));
              this.searching = false;
              this.loaded = true;
              this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
            } else {
              this.store.dispatch(fromSharedStore.SearchIbmers({ search: { q } }));
            }
          })
      );
```

every thing is okay when selecting from store returns a value but when x is undefined it dispatches an action to get the data in this line

```
else {
              this.store.dispatch(fromSharedStore.SearchIbmers({ search: { q } }));
            }
```

for now i need to re-select again after getting the data.

Comment: I guess something is wrong with your effects workflow. can you elaborate your problem statement not technically?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear enough.
Does your current code works fine now and you need to add a new calling to "re-select" or you have a problem with the mentioned code?